# Changing a WSDL to add parameters to existing SOAP API call

Tags: python, api, soap, wsdl, salesforce

I am working on an application using zeep and wsdl to call a SOAP api. The wsdl has a function that is pulling ~15 fields from salesforce, which are later written to a csv file (through python). I need to add a few fields to this request.

Is there any way of checking all the available fields from the api? The relevant complex type looks something like this:

```
 <xsd:complexType name="All_Fields">
  <xsd:sequence>
   <xsd:element name="FIELD_1" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
   <xsd:element name="FIELD_2" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
   <xsd:element name="FIELD_3" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
   ...
```

The output csv has these 3 fields. If I add this row to my wsdl underneath Field_3, I get a new column in my csv called Field_4, but it is an empty column

```
<xsd:element name="FIELD_4" minOccurs="0" type="xsd:string" nillable="true"/>
```

As of now, I am unaware of the exact names of the required fields. Would I need to know those, or is there a way of getting a list of all fields being returned in the api response? For now, I have been told the new fields exist in Salesforce (I can't see them in the WSDL though)

If I am entirely on the wrong track, please advise whether this is something that can be done from my end - changing the python/xml files, or if the salesforce api needs to be changed.

I have a targetNamespace at the top of the file and a soap:address at the end

```
targetNamespace="http://soap.sforce.com/schemas/class/MY_API_NAME" 
soap:address location="https://MYPROJECT.my.salesforce.com/services/Soap/class/MY_API_NAME"
```

Are these links usable to find what data is being returned? Similarly, are these links usable to look at all available parameters etc.?

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a real answer, bits and pieces too long for a comment...

Salesforce admin could just give you a new WSDL document with new fields. You can edit it yourself but it's work and for them it's just few clicks to generate new one. You need field name, true - but also type ;)

There's 2nd layer to this, SF APIs work on "need to know" basis. You likely got username and password to connect to SF. That user's "profile" must allow you to see/edit database tables and columns, otherwise you'll get errors even if you guess right field name.

I don't know what exactly you're doing. Are you calling standard salesforce API (making query yourself) or did they expose to you a custom webservice (you mentioned there's a class in that WSDL file?).

If you're calling standard APIs (raw query, create, delete etc calls) then absolutely, there are "[describe](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_calls_list_describe.htm)" calls that would give you info which tables and columns you can see. They should be listed in that WSDL or maybe your Python library implements them already, would save you some XML crafting. I know nothing about zeep, sorry. I heard https://pypi.org/project/simple-salesforce/ is well documented and easy to use, has describe calls built-in but it uses REST API, not SOAP...

(Salesforce WSDL files come in "enterprise" and "partner" flavours. Enterprise means all tables and columns are listed - but you want to see new field you need to generate fresh WSDL and consume it in your app again. "Partner" contains only these generic calls so at runtime you check what tables are there, what fields, types... Good for writing generic backup solutions or apps that can connect to any SF in the world. Sounds like you got an enterprise WSDL - but it'll still contain these generic calls, you can use them if needed)

If you're calling a custom Apex class exposed as webservice then well - SF people need to modify that code for you to see more fields in the response. Not much you can do on your end. If you decide REST route is much simpler for you then the custom SF code has to be exposed slightly differently, they'll have to read up about [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_rest_code_sample_basic.htm)

So yeah. Some random pieces of info. You have some reading and decisions to do. Just make sure you don't code yourself into a corner.